# Example of a non-affine scheme whose reduction is affine

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

In Hartshorne Exercise III.3.1, he asks the reader to prove that a noetherian scheme $X$ is affine iff $X_{\bf{red}}$ is affine. I am not sure if Noetherian is needed here (of course I only know the proof for the Noetherian case). So I was wondering if there is an example for a non-affine (non-noetherian) scheme $X$ for which its reduction $X_{\bf red}$ is affine?

Comment: See [this MO-duplicate](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95/is-there-an-example-of-a-scheme-x-whose-reduction-x-red-is-affine-but-x-is-not-a).

Comment: Oh thanks for showing me a link to a duplicate question (I couldn't find it when I searched before). If I understood that post correctly, so far no one has found an example and this seems to be an open question. Though it seems generally for "interesting" schemes $X$ is affine.

Comment: Feel free to vote to close the queston as there is a duplicated in MO. Thanks again for the duplicate link.

Comment: 1) Your first comment is incorrect. This is not open, any scheme $X$ with $X_{red}$ affine must also be affine. 2) It is impossible to close this as a duplicate because this question and the duplicate are on different sites: this question is on MSE, and the link provided by Dietrich Burde is on MO. 3) As a solution, I've copied over the accepted answer at MathOverflow in to a community-wiki post so that this question may be marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a community-wiki post recording the accepted answer [here on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95/is-there-an-example-of-a-scheme-x-whose-reduction-x-red-is-affine-but-x-is-not-a) so that this question may be marked as answered.

[David Rydh](https://mathoverflow.net/users/40/david-rydh):

> No, if $X$ is any algebraic space such that $X_{red}$ is an affine scheme, then $X$ is an affine scheme. This follows from Chevalley's theorem. For $X$ noetherian scheme/alg. space this theorem is in EGA/Knutson. As you noted, this can also be showed using Serre's criterion for affineness or by an even simpler argument (see EGA I 5.1.9, first edition).
>
> For $X$ **non-noetherian**, the following general version of Chevalley's theorem is proved in my paper "Noetherian approximation of algebraic spaces and stacks" ([arXiv:0904.0227](https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.0227)):
>
> **Theorem**: Let $W\to X$ be an integral and surjective morphism of algebraic spaces. If $W$ is an affine scheme, then so is $X$.
>
> Recall that any finite morphism is integral, in particular $X_{red} \to X$. As a corollary, it follows that under the same assumptions, if $W$ is a scheme then so is $X$.

In the comments to that answer, [R. van Dobben de Bruyn](https://mathoverflow.net/users/82179/r-van-dobben-de-bruyn) points out that the result for schemes is already contained in Conrad's note [*Deligne's notes on Nagata compactification*](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/papers/nagatafinal.pdf) as corollary A.2:

> **Corollary A.2**: If $X\to Y$ is a finite surjection of affine schemes with $X$ affine then $Y$ is affine. In particular, if $Y$ is a scheme so that $Y_{red}$ is affine then $Y$ is affine.